# List comprehension using multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I was unable to determine a Pythonic way for generating a list using list comprehension from multiple lists.  I'm trying to generate a list that implements the following function:

vbat = Vmax - a + b + c

Where Vmax is a constant but a, b and c are lists.  I was hoping I could do something that's easy to read like this:

```
vbat = [Vmax - x + y + z for x in a and y in b and z in c]
```

I know that I can use the map operator to make a new combined list and then use a list comprehension on the new list but it seems a little ugly and hard to read.  The code that I know would work is shown below:

```
newlist = map(sub,map(add,b,c),a)
vbat = [Vmax + x for x in newlist]
```

Is there a solution to this that is friendlier for the reader?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the product? Then just nest `for` loops, left to right: `for x in a for y in b for z in c`. The `map()` suggests you are looking for `zip()` instead however: `for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)`

Comment: I'm not sure where you are referring to a product, I simply want to subtract the element of list a and add the elements of lists b and c to a scalar and return a new list.  The answer provided below accomplishes the task I was referring to, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `zip` function can combine multiple lists into a sequence of tuples:

```
[Vmax - a_el + b_el + c_el for (a_el, b_el, c_el) in zip(a, b, c)]
```